# How to open a URL with specific settings?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, android-websettings

Hi, everybody.

This is my code. I've created a menu in my app. One of the items opens a URL correctly. But I would like to open the URL in a `WebView` with this `WebSettings`. But it doesn't work.

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case WEBSITE:
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "About", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.english.com/about");
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        WebView web = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        startActivity(it);
        return true;
```

Those web settings don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Starting the Browser to view a webpage means you're subjecting yourself to however the browser will present the url, and you have no control over the defined settings of another Application.  If you're trying to use your own `WebView`, you'll load the URL like this:

```
 webview.loadUrl("http://www.english.com/about");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you are doing wrong: 1) you create a new `WebView` but never attach it to your view tree and 2) you ask an outside app to handle the viewing of the url you want to display. You need to either add the `WebView` to your xml layout file or attach to the view tree by using `view.addChild(web);` on your root view. Once the `WebView` is part of your view tree just call `web.loadUrl(...);` to load the web page. Since you don't want to open the web page on an external browser, you should just get rid of your `Intent it =...` and `startActivity(it);`.

If you want to open the web page on a different activity, just create a new activity with a webview in its layout. You can find an example on how to do it [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/).